# How to insert a null value in SQL Server from C++

Tags: c++, sql-server, unicode

I am using an INSERT statement and want to set a field value to null when its not provided and this a little confusing.

The field (call it `name`) is type `nvarchar` in SQL Server. It was being set to `name ="NULL";` in C++ in the INSERT statement and it appeared as *NULL* in SQL server (note shows in italic in sql server).

After I changed the INSERT query to become UNICODE compatible and adding `N'NULL'` per Microsoft documentation, it now appears as `'NULL'` in SQL server (not shown in itatic and has extra ' around it ).

What is the different between *`NULL`* and `'NULL'`? How can I set this field to real NULL when the field value is empty?

**Update**

From comments sections Adrew mentioned just insert NULL for name field which shows up `(null)` in SQL server, yet another type.

I ran the following query in SQL management studio itself to find which one is the real null.

```
SELECT [NAME], [CITY] FROM TABLE WHERE NAME IS NULL
```

This returns only those items which were set with ASCII "NULL" value. It's even more confusing.

Comment: `'NULL'` is a string. That's what you're inserting, not a null value.  Completely different things.

Comment: @Andrew that's sound like it but funny thing is it doesn't complain about duplicate entries when its that, otherwise it does. But how do I set it correctly in unicode?

Comment: If you're trying to insert a null, you shouldn't need to worry about unicode.  `Insert into table foo (col1, col2,...) values (N'blah',NULL,...)`.

Comment: @Andrew nice, I tried that and it inserts `(null)` in SQL server (this is how it looks like in SQL. Now this sound like a real null...still wonder why these 3 types now and they all behave good! (allowing duplicates)

Comment: I think using name =N'' should also work even if the solution provided in your update is probably cleaner.